# Trying to fix textfieldDidBeginEditing & textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: swift

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField1.isTouchInside == true {
        textField1.text = ""
    }else {
        textField1.text = "TOP"
    }
    if textField2.isTouchInside == true {
        textField2.text = ""
    }else {
        textField2.text = "BOTTOM"
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
    if textField1.text == "" {
        textField1.text = "TOP"
    }

    if textField2.text == "" {
        textField2.text = "BOTTOM"
    }
}
```

textFieldDidBeginEditing is supposed to empty the textField when I click into the text field. textFieldDidEndEditing should return TOP or BOTTOM when the textField is empty.

Comment: What is the issue? did you getting error or not working?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set textFields delegates

```
textField1.delegate = self
textField2.delegate = self
```

After that you can getting result what you want using this code

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    textField.text = ""
    if textField == textField1 {
        textField2.text = "BOTTOM"
    }else if textField == textField2{
        textField1.text = "TOP"
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {

    if textField == textField1 && textField.text == ""{
        textField1.text = "TOP"
    }else if textField == textField2 && textField.text == ""{
        textField2.text = "BOTTOM"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dilan, I assigned the delegate already but the bug persists.

Comment: @Sola what is the bug?

Comment: It keeps wiping the text in the first textField.

Answer (score 0):

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

```
    if textField1.text == "TOP" && textField1.isTouchInside == true {
        textField1.text = ""
    } else if textField2.text == "BOTTOM" && textField2.isTouchInside == true {
               textField2.text = ""
           }
}
```